# SQuirreL Plugin Tutorial

Tags: java, plugins, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I have an idea for a plugin for [SQuirreL SQL client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) and I'd like to know how to make a plugin. My plugin will be a query builder UI which needs access to the schema model including tables, columns, primary keys, foreign keys and constraints etc.

I have searched the web for SQurreL plugin information / tutorials and I can't find much. The best I can find is on Wikipedia which is quite brief.

- http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQuirreL_SQL_Client_Plugin_API

If you have any links, tutorials, examples or any other information on creating SQuirreL plugins, please post them here.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a class for extending a Squirrel Plugin made in Java:

```
public class FulltextsearchPlugin extends DefaultSessionPlugin {  
private final Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();  
private final String path = "c:/temp/lucene/squirrel/";  
private final IndexWriter writer = createIndexWriter();  

@Override  
public String getAuthor() {  
    return "Mike Haller";  
}  

@Override  
public String getDescriptiveName() {  
    return "Full-Text Search Plugin";  
}  

@Override  
public String getInternalName() {  
    return "fulltextsearchplugin";  
}  

@Override  
public String getVersion() {  
    return "0.0.1";  
}  

@Override  
public PluginSessionCallback sessionStarted(ISession session) {  
    // Add context menu items to the object tree's view and procedure nodes.  
    IObjectTreeAPI otApi = session.getSessionInternalFrame()  
            .getObjectTreeAPI();  
    otApi.addToPopup(DatabaseObjectType.TABLE, new FulltextsearchMenu(this,  
            session));  
    return new PluginSessionCallbackAdaptor(this);  
 }  
}
```

That is a code snapshot from one of the best tutorials in my view, which provides a very clear discussion with steps on how to get a [plugin implemented](http://www.mhaller.de/archives/111-Extending-SQuirreL-with-plugins.html). The material provides a good template to extend it to other cases.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I can get access to the schema model via  session.getObjectTreeAPIOfActiveSessionWindow()